# How to pass session username to controller class using ajax jQuery in PHP cordelgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

[image]

I'm using the below script to execute a SQL query to change a database column value  when a user clicks a button. My SQL query is inside my controller class and whenever I hardcode the session username at the controller class my script works successfully and it also update my database column status. All I want is to pass the session username to the controller. Please help me to change this...

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#birthdaycard1").slideToggle(3000);        
         $("#id").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();

         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',   
                url: 'http://localhost/devinsnew/index.php/welcome/changeStatusCard'

        });

      });
});
        </script>
```

//my method at the controller class

```
  public function changeStatusCard($user) {

        $query = $this->db->query("update customer_info set card_status = 'Displayed' where username = '$user';");

    }
```

//This is my session code..

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: where's your session code?

Comment: More code please... I cant believe how often I've written that over that last week!

Comment: Sorry I just added that to my code

Comment: @AdamJeffers if you have done similar kind of thing or you know how to fix this can you please help me out. It's kind of urgent thing for me

Comment: Yeh give me 10/15 mins to take a look and can we please see the rest of your session code?

Comment: And where are you getting 'username' from... Im assuming there's some HTML infront of all this? We really need to see it all mate

Comment: yah sure take your time.. actually I dont have any other session codes in this page as once it is started it goes for each and every page untill user logout. Even I can display username in my page by useing only 'echo   $user = $_SESSION['username'];' .. So my session is successfully working

Comment: I'm really sorry I can post my whole code but it is really lenghty as I have some functions inside... About the session part that's all I have.. If you wanna go through my whole page just leave a comment I'll add it to my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but you can try it:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',   
            url: 'http://localhost/devinsnew/index.php/welcome/changeStatusCard'
            data:{
                'user': "<?=$_SESSION['your_key']?>"
            }
    });
```

but in this case the username will be visible in the source page.

Comment: No it is not working.. It is not passing the username to my controller

Comment: But do you have an username set ? Please tel me what is written in souce page `data: ` ?

Comment: Do you display the username somewhere in page? I hope you did what is said in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317676/php-access-session-variable-value-in-html-code/33317734#33317734) post

Comment: Yes on my header section it displays the username and also anywhere as the session is already working...It displays in my page

Comment: Please can you look in network tab from console browser to see what request is sent?

Comment: I'm really sorry I didn't understand what you asked me to do

Comment: Ok open site in Chrome. then press `F12`. Go to network tag (clear tab to be more easy to follow it) then click on your button and tell me what request was sent.

Comment: Ok just give me a sec

Comment: If you can please look into this..I just added a screen shot of the network tag  and the request which it sent was changeStatusCard (the name of my function in controller)

Comment: Ok, but it is important what is sent in form data for this request